# Как узнать точное место установки

Tags: python

и так я хочу установить Konas.jar, но как сделать проверки, мне нужно так, если по директории
C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods есть папка 1.12.2, то файл устанавливается в неё, если её нету, то файл устанавливается в C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods, а если самой папки C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods нету, то он выводит error в консоль

Comment: посмотрите в сторону встроенной библиотеки `os`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так можно

```py
from os.path import exists

path = "C:\\Users\\romaz\\AppData\\Roaming.minecraft\\mods"

if exists(path):
  if exists(f"{path}\\1.12.2"):
    install_jar(f"{path}\\1.12.2") # функция установки
  else:
    install_jar(path) # функция установки
else:
  print(f"Directory {path} does not exist")
```

Двойные слэши обязательны для экранирования.

Comment: сейчас проверим

Comment: r"C:\Users\romaz\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\mods" и двойные слэши не нужны